# What would the compiler do in this situation?

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-construction

I am wondering about this question:

How would a compiler modify your source code - to make it more efficient - if you would have the following line of code in your program?

```
int z = max(x,y);  // assume that x and y are of type int
```

given this function:

```
inline int max (int a, int b)
{
  return (a > b) ? a : b;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a homework question missing its context.

Comment: That would largely depend on a lot of things.  If `z` is never used, it would get rid of the entire line.  You aren't providing enough information to be able to suggest what the compiler might do.

Comment: I guess `int z = unicorn(x,y);` (if you compile it with `-Dmax=unicorn`)

Comment: I think the bigger question here is what would Brian Boitano do?

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't. Compilers don't modify source code; they just generate object code from the source code.

Assuming that `max` started out as something like this:

```
int max(int a, int b) { 
    return b < a ? b : a; 
}
```

...chances are pretty good that (at least on architectures that support it<sup>1</sup>), a good compiler would generate code like:

```
    mov eax, a
    mov ebx, b
    cmp eax, ebx
    jl  do_ret
    mov eax, ebx
do_ret:
    ret
```

Which, in terms of source code corresponds to something a little more like this:

```
int ret = a;
if (b < ret)
    ret = b;
return ret;
```

The primary advantage of this is that it requires only an if/then, not an if/then/else. The latter typically requires at least one extra branch to execute the two legs separately, then bring the flow of execution back together afterward.

---

1. In this case, supporting it is pretty easy. In a few cases, you run into a situation where it's easiest to do the comparison, then load one value as the default, then branch on the result of the comparison. This requires an architecture where the flags are *not* modified by loads. That's true on x86, for one example, but wasn't on many others (68K comes to mind, though it's been too long for me to trust my memory on that).

Comment: Isn't a `cmov` way more likely?

Comment: @Oak: It's certainly entirely possible, but (unlike those I've mentioned above) doesn't really correspond very closely with different source code (which, I'd interpreted as being what his question was mostly about).

Answer (score 0):

This is a micro-optimization and usually the performance gain is negligible.

Depends on the declaration of `max()` and the target assembly language.

If `max()` is defined as:

```
#define max(a,b) ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

The function could be optimized as:

```
z = b;
if (b < a)
{
  z = a;
}
```

If your processor has conditional instructions then it could be optimized as:

```
COMPARE A, B;
MOV Z,B IF A LT B
MOV Z,A IF B LT A
```

Comment: given this function definition

Comment: inline int max (int a, int b)
    {
      return (a > b) ? a : b;
    }